# Zend 1 - Render another controller from a controller

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, controller, frameworks

I'm trying to change our current layout for requesting the controller contents by AJAX instead of reloading the page each time the user clicks on any item of the menu. Long story short: I need to load a controller from another controller. Let's say I have a controller named `AjaxController.php` that will receive the controller and action that it will need to render by POST and needs to return the requested controller HTML response without the layout.

Right now I only have the following code on the controller:

```
class AjaxhelperController extends Default_Model_Views_Basic
{
    protected $_redirector = null;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        $valor = $this->_request->getParam('valor');                                    
        $this->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();            
        $this->_redirector->gotoUrl('http://desarrollo.techmaker.net/eloy/svn/eplanv30/public/demo_eplan_profesional/gestordocumental/gestordocumental');
    }
}
```

The problem is it redirects to the page but loading the complete layout, I need to load it without the layout. Is there any way of doing this without needing to change each controller logic?

Answer (score 1):

To render another controller from current controller without page reloading you can use _forward() method:

_forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null): perform another action.

It will run another action from another controller. See details on the:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html

Comment: I maanaged to do it through the `Redirector` helper (See my edit question). The problem now is it's loaded with the full layout rendered.